# Shortcut to the command prompt in VisualStudio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VisualStudio Code, is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to the command prompt in the debug mode? It is somewhat tiresome to have to click at this prompt with the mouse every time.

[image]

**EDIT 1**

Using binding `workbench.debug.action.focusRepl` results in the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the debug console is closed, there is `View: Debug Console` (`workbench.debug.action.toggleRepl`) to open it. That one is bound to `cmd+shift+y` on macOS, should be `ctrl-shift-y` on Windows / Linux.

If the debug console is already open, you can either press the aforementioned shortcut twice or use the following command:

`Debug: Focus Debug Console`

It has no default shortcut, but you can bind it to whatever you like, the action is called:

`workbench.debug.action.focusRepl`

Comment: Double clicking `ctrl-shift-y` works but the action `workbench.debug.action.focusRepl` is not found. Is it the correct spelling/command?

Comment: Nope, double checked, the command name is correct. What are you doing exactly? You have to put something like this in your `keybindings.json` to bind a key: `{
        "key": "ctrl+alt+cmd+d",
        "command": "workbench.debug.action.focusRepl"
    }`

Comment: Is it working in your VSCode? I do have other keyboard binding and they work. Here after pressing the shortcut, VSCode detects the command but does not find it as a correct command and says it is not found. I added an edit with the screenshot.

Comment: Works fine here, I tested it with the above keybinding, but others should work too. Strange that you get this message. I'd recommend opening an issue on Github, maybe it bug that got something to do with the used operating system or any other installed extensions…